# Angular RouterReuseStrategy with optional route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have route only with two optional parameters. By default when I trying to navigate from one of this route to another nothing happens. And thats fine. I know about *routeParams.data.subscribe(...)* feature, but this approach doesn't suit to me, I need to full reinitialize component. That's why in my demo I use custom RouteReuseStrategy with flag *data {reuse: true}*. I borrow the RouteReuseStrategy [from here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12446#issuecomment-312754035).

Expected behaviour in demo: Go to "Home" tab, make some +1, сlick "Go to same route" button (this navigate to the same HomeViewComponent), HomeViewComponent must reinitialize and Counter must be 0.

But component not recreated, Counter is the same. [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-wzbrm6?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since Angular 5.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19463/commits/7a4a1a89e19cbdcc2e91a34ad32ab25233778d5d) you can use `onSameUrlNavigation` option when defining routes:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent },
  { path: ':one/:two', component: HomeViewComponent, data: {reuse: false} },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
], { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })
```

also change your `CustomRouteReuseStrategy::shouldReuseRoute` method as follows:

```
public shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.data.reuse !== undefined ? 
           future.data.reuse : 
           future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-sxulvf?file=app%2FcustomReuseStrategy.ts)**

Comment: Amazing, made my day!